# Segmentation fault na function read_line

Tags: c

Tenho uma function que retorna uma string de uma linha de um arquivo, porém ao executá-lo recebo uma mensagem de segmentation fault. Aqui vai o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "parser.h"

const int MAX_CHAR_PER_LINE = 100;

int main()
{
    FILE *h = fopen("/home/test.txt", "r");
    char *line = read_line(h);

    printf("%s", line);

    return 0;
}

int parse(FILE *header)
{

   return 0;
}

char* read(FILE *header, int bytes)
{
    char *ret_v = (char*) malloc(bytes);
    fread((void*) ret_v, 1, bytes, header);

    return ret_v;
}

char* read_line(FILE *header)
{
    char *line = (char*) malloc(MAX_CHAR_PER_LINE);
    char ch = getc(header);
    int count = 0;

    while (ch != 255 && ch != '\n')
    {
        line[count] = ch;
        ch = getc(header);
        count++;
    }
    line[++count] = '\0';

    char *ret_line;
    memcpy(ret_line, line, strlen(line));
    free(line);

    return ret_line;
}
```

Não entendo porque está dando esse erro, aparentemente fiz tudo certo. :/
Obs: Acabei de descobrir que o "erro" não está no código, e sim no compilador. Compilei com o TCC e apareceu o erro segfault, mas quando compilei com o gcc o function retornou o valor correto.

Comment: Mas se o objetivo é ler o arquivo inteiro e colocar em um `char *`, porque não simplesmente definiu isto no `fread` e usou `fseek` para saber o tamanho que deveria ler o `rewind` para voltar o ponteiro ao começo antes de usar o `fread`? ... Claro que se o arquivo for grande, eu acho que isso nem vale a pena, seria melhor ler com limites e ir imprimindo na tela (que parece ser o objetivo)

Comment: Sim o arquivo será grande, por isso que quero ler linha por linha.

Comment: Então se quer ler linha por linha esta fazendo isso "errado" (do meu ponto de vista), alocar um arquivo grande na memória me parece uma estratégia ruim, tenho que entender o seu objetivo para no minimo tentar lhe indicar uma solução estratégica de como fazer isto. Simplesmente ler por ler não parece o objetivo real da sua aplicação, se puder dar uma ideia do que pretende fazer com os dados lidos eu poderei tentar apontar um caminho.

Comment: Acabei de "resolver o problema", meu objetivo é extrair functions dentro dos headers para em breve criar uma IDE para C.

Comment: @CarlosHenrique responda e pergunte e aceite, fica melhor para deixar o registro.

Comment: Então @CarlosHenrique dá para fazer isso sem jogar tudo na memoria, dá para tipo criar um identificador de TOKENs (supondo que você esteja criando uma "linguagem propria"), os TOKENs seriam palavras reservadas de suas funções que poderiamos detectar a cada loop e só alocar na memoria o que é importante ... é sério você não precisa alocar todo o arquivo na memoria, isso vai matar a sua aplicação, ou no minimo dar CRASH.

Comment: Entendo, mas no caso eu iria alocar na memória apenas uma linha, e apartir dessa linha iria identificar os tokens

Comment: Então, mas o erro provavelmente esta ocorrendo no teu script porque fez isto, alocou tudo de uma vez, o que precisa fazer é o que eu comentei anteriormente, ler de pedaço em pedaço e só alocar o que interessar para ti.

Comment: Poderia me enviar um exemplo?

Comment: Como é o formato do conteudo deste seu .txt?

Comment: Formato de texto, ASCII text

Comment: Como `char` só armazena um único byte (e esse byte tem bit de sinal), creio que a comparação `ch != 255` não retornará o que pretende. A propósito, por questões de otimização, lê-se uma ruma de bytes de uma vez só, no lugar de sempre ir no arquivo para puxar um novo caracter. Não que isso esteja errado, só é desnecessariamente lento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não deve haver nenhum problema com o seu compilador. O problema do seu código está no fim da função `read_line`:

```
char *ret_line;
memcpy(ret_line, line, strlen(line));
free(line);
return ret_line;
```

A assinatura da função memcpy é a seguinte:

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

O que a função `memcpy` faz é copiar `num` bytes no endereço apontado por `source` e coloca esses bytes no endereço apontado por `destination`. O que siginifica que `memcpy` não aloca memória para o ponteiro `destination`. Você está copiando bytes para um ponteiro não inicializado. Esta é a causa do *segmentation fault*. Então o correto seria fazer assim:

```
char *ret_line = (char*) malloc(strlen(line)); 
memcpy(ret_line, line, strlen(line));
free(line);
return ret_line;
```

Mas para copiar strings existe uma alternativa melhor, que seria a `strcpy`. O código ficaria praticamente o mesmo, você só não teria que especificar o número de bytes, pois a função copeia até achar o caracter de terminação.

Mas na verdade você nem precisa de nada disso, você poderia retornar o ponteiro `line`. E não esqueça de libertar a memória na função main.

Comment: Chegou tarde, eu já havia resolvido o problema